# How to document response fields for an object as Map(HashMap)

Tags: spring-restdocs

I am doing documentation for a REST service returning an object like this:

```
Map<String, HashMap<Long, String>>
```

and i find no way to describe response fields for such object.

Let's have a look at my code.

The service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, HashMap<Long, String>> getData()
 {
Map<String, HashMap<Long, String>> list = dao.getData();
return list;
}
```

My unit-test-based documentation:

```
  @Test
  public void testData() throws Exception
  {
    TestUtils.beginTestLog(log, "testData");

    RestDocumentationResultHandler document = document(SNIPPET_NAME_PATTERN ,preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));    
    document.snippets(
 //        ,responseFields(
 //            fieldWithPath("key").description("key description").type("String"),
 //            fieldWithPath("value").description("value as a Hashmap").type("String"),
 //            fieldWithPath("value.key").description("value.key description").type("String"),
 //            fieldWithPath("value.value").description("value.value description").type("String"),
 //        )

      String token = TestUtils.performLogin(mockMvc, "user", "password");

    mockMvc
    .perform(get(APP_BUILD_NAME + "/svc/data").contextPath(APP_BUILD_NAME)
        .header("TOKEN", token)
    )
    .andExpect(status().is(200))
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$").isMap())
    .andDo(document);

    TestUtils.endTestLog(log, "testData");
 }
```

As you can see the code for response fields is commented out since I haven't had any solution for it yet. I am working on that but i really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the JSON that you're trying to document look like?

Comment: Have a look at the JSON with this link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64513069/JSONData_Translation.txt

The data is big, but i think i just need to document 3 things for the object Map<String, HashMap<Long, String>>.

Comment: Hello Andy,
I can make description for response fields of a List of objects. And this requires me to change using List instead of MAP as before. But the problem is that we need the MAP. Could you possibly share your opinion if I can work with MAP on description for Response fields or not. 

If it is impossible, I can came up with other solution by skipping description for response fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I probably am later for the party. But, is there any way that I can see a sample of your `HashMap<Long, String>` initialized with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1> Changing MAP to LIST of objects so that the response fields can be described easily.

2> Putting description manually to index.adoc file.

In my case, I go for option 2 because I have to stick to MAP.

Comment: **There are two options:..** is not entirely correct. You can document a map...

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON contains a huge number of different fields. There looks to be over 1000 different entries in the map. Each of those entries is itself a map with a single key-value pair. Those keys all appear to vary as well. Potentially, that gives you over 2000 fields to document:

- `cancel`
- `cancel.56284`
- `year`
- `year.41685`
- `segment_de_clientele`
- `segment_de_clientele.120705`
- `…`

This structure is making it hard to document and is also a strong indicator that it will be hard to consume by clients. Ideally, you would restructure the JSON so that each entry has the same keys and it's only the values the vary from entry to entry. Something like this, for example:

```
{
  "translations": [ {
    "name": "cancel",
    "id": 56284,
    "text": "Exit"
  }, {
    "name": "year",
    "id": 41685,
    "text": "Year"
  }, {
    "name": "segment_de_clientele",
    "id": 120705,
    "text": "Client segment"
  }]
}
```

This would mean that you only have a handful of fields to document:

- `translations[]`
- `translations[].name`
- `translations[].id`
- `translations[].text`

If that's not possible, then I'd stop trying to use the response fields snippet to document the structure of the response. Instead, you should describe its structure manually in your main Asciidoctor source file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your solution is great but I have to change my returned object from Map<String, HashMap<Long, String>>  to List<Translations> and the Purpose of using Map is different from List. I would like to ask if there's any way for documenting such Map object. I mean for example name, id and test documented. You said the data is huge but actually with the Map i just care about those 3 fields which I'd like to document.