# Spring rest docs nested object

Tags: spring-restdocs

We need to deliver a response for a call in the following form:

```
{
  "3" : {
    "id" : "3",
    "parent" : "1",
    "title" : "Folder 2",
    "folder" : true
  },
  "4" : {
    "id" : "4",
    "parent" : "2",
    "title" : "Folder 1.1",
    "folder" : true
  },
  "doc:3" : {
    "parent" : "3",
    "title" : "Document 3",
    "folder" : false
  },
  "doc:2" : {
    "parent" : "2",
    "title" : "Document 2",
    "folder" : false
  },
  "doc:1" : {
    "parent" : "3",
    "title" : "Document 1",
    "folder" : false
  }
}
```

How should i document it? The Problem is that the object is a structure with EntryId as key and contains no id when its a document. Is there a option where I can use variables to define keys? Or whats recomended to use in responseFields ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document response fields for an object as Map(HashMap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432282/how-to-document-response-fields-for-an-object-as-maphashmap)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that Andy Wilkinson is pointing in the comments and instead of hardcode it in the ascii.doc, I did it like so:

```
  ,relaxedResponseFields(
     fieldWithPath("key").description(getMessage(MessageProperties.TRANSLATION_RESOURCE_MAP_KEY)).type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING).optional(),
     fieldWithPath("value").description(getMessage(MessageProperties.TRANSLATION_RESOURCE_MAP_KEY_VALUE)).type(MessageProperties.TYPE_MAP).optional(),
     fieldWithPath("value[].key").description(getMessage(MessageProperties.TRANSLATION_RESOURCE_MAP_KEY_VALUE_KEY)).type(MessageProperties.TYPE_LONG).optional(),
     fieldWithPath("value[].value").description(getMessage(MessageProperties.TRANSLATION_RESOURCE_MAP_KEY_VALUE_KEY_VALUE)).type(MessageProperties.TYPE_STRING).optional()
  )
```

check [How to document response fields for an object as Map(HashMap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432282/how-to-document-response-fields-for-an-object-as-maphashmap) for more info of the problem and if it really like yours.